# How to use javascript in .ascx pages

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net, jquery, ascx

How to use javascript in .ascx pages

Comment: by the `<script>` tag, perchance? is there anything more specific you're wondering?

Answer (score 19):

You can add script tags to the markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // place your javascript here
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" href="path to js file" />
```

Or use [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) in the code behind so you don't include the same file/js section multiple times if you use multiple controls in a page.

You can find out more about `ScriptManager` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx) (overview, including usage scenarios).

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that you included the JavaScript code within `script` tags in the user control page.

I'm also assuming that you are calling a function from one of the controls within the user control

Another assumption I'm making is that your user control is hidden at the loading time.

If the user control is in an `UpdatePanel` and/or its `Visible` attribute is set to `false` by default, you will get "`Object expected`" error because simply your script is not loaded when the page loads and the function you are calling is non-existent.

Workaround for this is to use `style="display:none"` instead of `Visible="false"` for your user control in the main page.